# How to call CMS Block via its identifier in Product edit / add page?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, cms-block

I want to call a **CMS Block** via its `identifier` in a **product attribute** to display **CMS block on product page**.

- Want to **show different Static Block**  on  **different products**

So how can I achieve this via **attribute** where I can enter **identifier of CMS block**?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

**Update:**

```
themeVendor/themeName/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml
```

> Block ID: shipping_test
>
> attribute ID: size_map

```
<?php if ($_additional = $block->getAdditionalData()): ?>
<div class="additional-attributes-wrapper table-wrapper">
<table class="data table additional-attributes" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
<caption class="table-caption"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('More Information') ?></caption>
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>

<?php if ($_data['label'] == "size_map") { ?>

<tr>
<th class="col label" scope="row"><?php echo $_data['label'] ?></th>
<td class="col data"><b class="mobilelabel"><?php echo $_data['label'] ?>: </b>
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId($_data['value'])->toHtml() ?>
</td>
</tr>


<?php } else { ?>


<tr>
<th class="col label" scope="row"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
<td class="col data" data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__($_data['label'])) ?>"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
</tr>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Is this within the attribute grid?

Comment: please check updated question

Comment: Im still a bit confused. In my example you will get a different static block on different products. It will depend on the attribute value. If the attribute value is shipping1 then the shipping1 static block is shown, shipping2 then the shipping2 block will show etc. Is this not what you want?

Comment: my mistake , its not shipping .... anything can be inside that block.... any information .... just need to show different blocks on different products ....

Comment: Well the blocks can be named anything and can include any information. its just an example... Do you intend to set the block based on an attribute within product?

Comment: Like i did this before with Brand. I select the brand from brand dropdown from admin for that product then created static blocks for each brand. On the product pages the static block is then called for that brand within a tab .

Comment: not dropdown, in text box need to pass identifier value

Comment: Well it will be the same just easier.

Comment: My code does just that. Grab attribute:
$shippingtype = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('shippingtype')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
Then use attribute value to grab static block by that value:
$block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId($shippingtype)->toHtml();

Comment: Just change your attribute value and your good to go

Comment: As it shows in my answer this can be done slightly different in attributes grid but is basically the same it waits for the loop to hit your attribute where you have set the identifier then uses the value of that attribute to set the static block.

Comment: I have updated my question with how it should be to check against attribute codes we were checking against the label so if your if statment was = "Size Map" it would of probably fired ( if that was your label)

Comment: Do this code can output Block content. Just confirming: <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId($_data['value'])->toHtml() ?>

Comment: Yeah that does just output a static block based on identifier

Comment: Did you get it going??

Comment: I left for the day in evening  ,  will see this tomorrow ...  thanks for your help buddy...will update

Comment: No worries have a gooden

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a template with below code:

```
<?php
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$shippingtype = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('shippingtype')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
$shippingtypetext = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId($shippingtype)->toHtml();
?>
<p><?php echo $shippingtypetext; ?></p>
```

You would need to create the 4 static blocks with static block identifiers with the same identifier as the attribute values.

> **Calling a static block based on attribute:**

```
$block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId($shippingtype)->toHtml();
```

Will get a static block based on identifier. I grabbed an attribute value and used that within **setBlockId($attrvalue)** so that **different static blocks** show within **different products** depending on what block you reference in the attribute value.

> **Example within Frontend Attribute Grid Tab**

For example within the **attribute grid** you could do something like below added within the foreach loop for attributes. Once the shipping_type is reached a new bit of code will be used that pulls a static block with that identifier rather than calling the attribute value:

```
        <?php if ($_data['code'] == "shipping_type"):?>
            <tr>
                <th class="col label" scope="row"><?php echo $_data['label'] ?></th>
                <td class="col data"><b class="mobilelabel"><?php echo $_data['label'] ?>: </b><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId($_data['value'])->toHtml()</td>
            </tr>
        <?php else: ?>
             <tr>
                <th class="col label" scope="row"><?php echo $_data['label'] ?></th>
                <td class="col data"><b class="mobilelabel"><?php echo $_data['label'] ?>: </b><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
            </tr>
     <?php endif; ?>
```

> **themeVendor/themeName/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml**

Comment: block content is not displaying. what can be the reason ? please

Comment: Maybe just echo the attribute code see that it matches. Try manually inputting the code that you know works to check the code for the block code is working.

Comment: Add your code to question so i can take a look also

Comment: see updated question, code added

Comment: im thinking the data label is different to the attribute code. Change the if statement to match the label or query against $_data['code']

Comment: Also you dont need my first section of code really that was more generic for other blocks. You have all the code you need within the for each loop.

Comment: Awesome. No worries Manoj!

Comment: could you check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/195275/54588

Comment: I have put a starting point on question could do with a lot of work and may make a proper module however when have time.

Comment: No worries it's a handy feature tho im interested in improving as much as possible to and add to some stores.