# How to achieve "shipping countdown timer" for delivery feature?

Tags: magento2, shipping

I am trying to develop  a module/functionality **shipping deadline countdown timer**  on product page.

**This timer will notify customers** about **expected delivery date** if a purchase is made before the timer reaches **zero**

[See working example here on amazon](https://www.amazon.in/JBL-Portable-Wireless-Bluetooth-Speaker/dp/B00TFGWAA8/ref=lp_14133605031_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1506680661&sr=1-1)

[image]

I should able to **set delivery days and cut off time for products** in admin

**Note:** On `Magento1` can be achieved via using this extension: [Shipping Deadline Countdown](https://marketplace.magento.com/nublue-nublue-countdowntimer.html)

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Yeah okay bhai. Thanks for suggestions. :)

Answer (score 5):

This is just a simple outline of how i would start going about it and could do with finishing however:

**Get the time:**

```
$currenttime = strtotime(date("h:i:s A"));
```

**Get the cutoff time or just set manually for now:**

```
$cutofftime = strtotime(date('h:i:s A', strtotime(date('d-m-Y') . ' + 16 hours')));
```

Gets the current day and adds 16 hours for cut off time of 16:00

**Get Delivery Time or set manually for now:**

```
$deliverydate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime(date('d-m-Y') . ' + 2 weekdays'));
```

**Need to change the day if passed cut off time:**

```
if ($currenttime>$cutofftime) {
    $cutofftime+= 86400;
    $deliverydate+= 86400;
}
```

**Calculate interval**

```
$interval = date('H:i:s', mktime(0, 0, $cutofftime-$currenttime));
```

**Then format data:**

```
<div>For delivery on <?php echo $deliverydate; ?> order within the next <span id="time"></span> minutes!</div>
```

**Javascript to make a countdown live:**

```
<script>
function startTimer(duration, display) {
var timer = duration, hours, minutes, seconds;
setInterval(function () {
    hours = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
        timer = duration;
    }
}, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
var time = <?php echo $cutofftime-$currenttime; ?>,
    display = document.querySelector('#time');
startTimer(time, display);
};
</script>
```

> **Full Example Code**

```
<?php
$currenttime = strtotime(date("h:i:s A"));
$cutofftime = strtotime(date('h:i:s A', strtotime(date('d-m-Y') . ' + 16 hours')));
$deliverydate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime(date('d-m-Y') . ' + 2 weekdays'));
if ($currenttime>$cutofftime) {
    $cutofftime = strtotime(date('h:i:s A', strtotime(date('d-m-Y') . ' + 40 hours')));
    $deliverydate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime(date('d-m-Y') . ' + 3 weekdays'));
}
$interval = date('H:i:s', mktime(0, 0, $cutofftime-$currenttime));

?>
<div>For delivery on <?php echo $deliverydate; ?> order within the next <span id="time"></span> minutes!</div>

<script>
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, hours, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        hours = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var time = <?php echo $cutofftime-$currenttime; ?>,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(time, display);
};
</script>
```

This is just something quite poor however that i have knocked up as concept. Could do with using Magento time and having some settings in back end for cut off time as well as pulling maybe delivery times for products.

**Current issues here:**

1. The delivery date is not updated will need to update when timer reaches 0.
2. Would like to change the minutes to include hours.
3. Make modular and include some admin settings for cut off time.
4. Would be good to get a shipping time from backend either from products or from shipping method.
5. Use magento time rather than PHP
6. Not sure about summer time and how this will work.

I will work a bit on this however and keep improving. I have started a git project which is in a worse state than this but now is a module and it shows up on product page counting down to the time set.

https://github.com/harrigo/Magento2-CountdownTimer

Comment: Yes I am working on it and will share the ideas to get it working up

Comment: check link given for magento 1 in question ...needs some admin setting as pointed in question and check on amazon ... on given link

Comment: I will try and work on this probably wont have time for a few days however. Have made a starting point on github however by making it a module

Comment: I've done configuration values in admin now on github although everything needs a lot of tweaking still but i think that's all i can do for today.

Comment: thanks bro... I ll see this on monday.... currently not on my system

Comment: No worries man have a good weekend

Comment: is there any update on this ?

Comment: Ive done a little work on it, been busy however with other bits so may be slow progress just needs exclude days and was going to set cut off time by day. Issues with adding 1 working day excluding certain bank holidays and stuff like that with javscript for if timer lapses while user on page.

Comment: I just tried your test module of github but its giving errors in compilation though seems working. Can you please let me know which magento version you are using. I tried it on 2.1.9

Comment: Yeah i never really finished it so it needs a lot of work. What is the error i though i solved the compilation error?

Comment: Your tested version ?

Comment: Just what is the error? i havent got extension installed anywhere at moment but thought it was upto date on what i had done on there.  A lot of the functionality doesn't work however i was going to add exclude days and stuff so some logic needs to be added to check if next few days within dleivery time includes any of those days and if so add the days to the timer. There are also a few more issues i cant really remember think it was when the timer lapses.

Comment: Ok. I just want to confirm version. And its possible that error because of 3rd part module. I will check and post back here. Error was in compile: 

 Harrigo\DeliveryCountdown\Block\DeliveryCountdown
                Incorrect dependency in class Harrigo\DeliveryCountdown\Block\DeliveryCountdown in /ROOT-PATH/app/code/Harrigo/DeliveryCountdown/Block/DeliveryCountdown.php
\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface already exists in context object.

ITs also possible that error is becasue of mazebuzz module but I am not sure.

Comment: Though your module works but it always start time from : 23:59:59. Rest of things seems working fine.

Comment: Yeah bit of a mess was just a start i made. Not sure when i will have time to finish it. The issue with compilation is because i injected a class in context however i can fix that quite quickly

Comment: So nice. I am waiting :)

Comment: Did you set the cut off time in admin?

Comment: yes. I did but its not effecting

Comment: Ok yeah ill take a look at it soon been meaning to spend a few hours on that

Comment: I am trying to update it and if things go fine, I will commit on git.

Comment: Awesome thanks. Yeah not sure why its starting at that time but should be simple enough to debug its a very simple little module at the moment.

Comment: And if you get some time to fix this then please do it. Big thanks for your efforts

Comment: I have to add excluded days in admin and recv those in block file -deliverycountdown like$cuttoffadmin = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('deliverycountdown/delivery/cutofftimemon', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
;

I want to use array as excluded days will be any number. If you throw some, it will great help.

Comment: I did start an array for exclude days so can be set in admin just need to pull them into the block and then write some php to check if any of the days are within the period in question.